Where can I specify a path for a root site within Joomla 5? Site failed to find test/en and gives The requested URL was not found on this server
Where can I specify a path for a root site within Joomla 5? Site failed to find test/en and gives The requested URL was not found on this server.
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu) Server at testweb. Port 443
Expecting to display english site of it
test other folders
/administrator and Joomla Admin works but not the actual site.

To use the language tag in the site address, you must activate the Joomla multilingual plugin
read document
https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Setup_a_Multilingual_Site
